# Finding a character and doing a command associated with that character in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have this following code here and basically I input a file and the file has certain commands on it. For instance, the file may look like this:

```
s
u 1
u 2
u 3
o 
o
o
```

Each of these characters has an associated command.

- `S`: Creates an empty stack.
- `u`: Pushes a value onto the stack.
- `o` pops a value off the stack and writes it onto an output file.

I have written the following code below but am unsure on how to proceed for the `u` and `o` commands.

```cpp
void Stack::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path) {

    string line; 
    ifstream myfile (input_path);
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (myfile.good()) {
            getline (myfile,line);
            while (!myfile.eof()) {
                if (line.find("c") == line.npos) {
                    cout << line << endl;
                }
                if (line.find("s")) {
                    Stack();
                }
                if (line.find("u")) {
                    // need to figure out this part
                }
            }
            
        } 
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn about `std::istringstream`. It might help you.

Comment: `Stack();` isn't going to do anything useful. Just create a temporary Stack and then dispose of it, though even that might be optimized out.

Comment: Consider changing your loop condition to `while(getline(myfile, line))` instead of checking `!myfile.eof()`.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts. Once a questions has received at least one useful answer, it cannot be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library has a [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) class.  I'm assuming `Stack` is a custom class for a school assignment?

You already know how to read lines from the input file.  You can use [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse those lines.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack> // <-- remove if you're not allowed to use std::stack
using namespace std;

void Stack::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path) {

    ifstream inputFile (input_path);
    ofstream outputFile (output_path);

    if (!inputFile.is_open() || !outputFile.is_open()) {
        return;
    }

    stack<int> stk; // or: Stack stk;
    string line; 

    while (getline (inputFile, line)) {
        istringstream iss (line);
        char cmd;

        if (!(iss >> cmd)) {
            continue;
        }

        switch (cmd) {
            case 's': {
                stk = stack<int>(); // or: stk = Stack();
                // alternatively, if using std::stack:
                // stack<int>().swap(stk);
                break;
            }

            case 'u': {
                int value;
                if (iss >> value) { 
                    stk.push(value);
                }
                break;
            }

            case 'o': {
                if (!stk.empty()) {
                    outputFile << stk.top() << '\n';
                    stk.pop();
                    // or: if your custom Stack has a pop() that returns the popped value:
                    // outputFile << stk.pop() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/19d7kD)