# using stoi when creating a stack data structure results in errors

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I've created a stack data structure and am implementing it. I've been using the function below,

```cpp
void Stack::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
    string line;
    Stack tempStack; 
    ifstream myfile(input_path);
    ofstream outfile(output_path);
    
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (line.substr(0,1) == "s") {
            Stack tempStack = Stack();
        };

        if (line.substr(0,1) == "e") {
            int a = stoi(line.substr(1,1));
            tempStack.push(a);
        };

        if (line.substr(0,1) == "o") {
            int a = stoi(line.substr(1,1));
            int num = tempStack.pop();
            string x = to_string(num);
            outfile <<  x << "";
        };        
    }
}
```

But the problem is this part of the code, unless it's not:

```cpp
if (line.substr(0,1) == "o") {
    int a = stoi(line.substr(1,1));
    int num = tempStack.pop();
    string x = to_string(num);
    outfile <<  x << "";
};
```

I'm getting this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

Abort trap: 6
```

I initially thought that the issue lied with the fact that I wasn't converting the `int num` to a `string`, but even I have, the error is no closer to being solved.

Comment: What's the result of `line.substr(1,1)` at that point? Check that with your debugger please, and add that information to your question ([edit]).

Comment: *"But the problem is this part of the code, unless it's not:"* -- yes, you certainly have covered all of your bases with this [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). You could probably confirm your guess by streaming something to `std::cerr` before and after that call to `stoi` (the function mentioned in the error), perhaps `std::cerr << "Before: \"" << line.substr(1,1) << "\"\n";` and `std::cerr << "After: " << a << "\n";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show what your input actually looks like, but if it is anything like the input shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591098/), then the `o` case does not have an integer value associated with it, so the call to `line.substr(1,1)` will not return a `string` that `std::stoi()` can convert to an `int`, hence why a `std::invalid_argument` exception is being thrown.  Which makes sense, since the `o` case is meant to only pop a value from the stack, not push a new value onto the stack.  So, just remove the call to `std::stoi()` altogether:

```cpp
if (line.substr(0,1) == "o") {
    //int a = stoi(line.substr(1,1)); // <-- get rid of this!
    int num = tempStack.pop();
    string x = to_string(num);
    outfile << x;
};
```

Also, you have 2 `tempStack` objects in scope inside of the `s` case. You are creating a 2nd `Stack` object that is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the existing `Stack` object, which is not what you want to happen. This code:

```cpp
Stack tempStack; 
...
if (line.substr(0,1) == "s") {
    Stack tempStack = Stack();
};
```

Should be this instead:

```cpp
Stack tempStack; 
...
if (line.substr(0,1) == "s") {
    tempStack = Stack();
};
```

So, with that said, your function should look more like this:

```cpp
void Stack::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
    string line;
    Stack tempStack; 
    ifstream myfile(input_path);
    ofstream outfile(output_path);
    
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (line.substr(0,1) == "s") {
            tempStack = Stack();
        }

        if (line.substr(0,1) == "e") {
            int a = stoi(line.substr(1,1));
            tempStack.push(a);
        }

        if (line.substr(0,1) == "o") {
            int num = tempStack.pop();
            string x = to_string(num);
            outfile << x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code you sent, they seem to be directly identical. In addition, I'm slightly lost on how to look into the stack object itself and pop an integer like you mentioned. Would just tempstack.pop() work below that if conditional?

Comment: "*In the code you sent, they seem to be directly identical*" - refresh your browser, I already fixed that. "*I'm slightly lost on how to look into the stack object itself and pop an integer like you mentioned*" - this is the code you showed, I just removed some things from it, not add or change anything else. So why are you lost? You have the source code for the `Stack` class, I don't. Look at the code and see what it actually provides.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was referring to your earlier answer and I don't think your edit had loaded at that point.